# Protocol buffer serialize into packets

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, packet, satellite

I need to send serialized data by satellite, which involves sending data as packets that have a maximum size of 2kB each.

Is there a built-in/easy way to serialize data with protobuf into packets limited to X size? And then rebuild them on the other end?

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf always serializes a message into one byte array which is as long as is needed to represent the data.

Your best bet is to split the bytes into chunks an a lower layer, then re-assemble at the other end.

In all likelihood, these packets are not reliably delivered, and so you will also need a mechanism for acknowledging packets, re-transmitting dropped packets, congestion control, etc. These are all things that TCP normally does for you. If I were you, I would look for an existing TCP implementation -- or something like it -- that can sit on top of your satellite link.